# Oracle live table replication

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, sqlplus

One my application is running on a table on oracle database which continuously update the records in table. Due to some requirement I need to make replica of live table but I don’t want to connect the application with replica table.
Is there any way to make replica of live tables?

Comment: *"Due to some requirement"*? Oracle has several different mechanisms for replication. Which one will suit you best really depends on what you want to do with the replicated data.

Answer (score 0):

Create a trigger after update and replicate your updated table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER blabla ON toto
AFTER UPDATE
AS
...
```

Comment: probably the least efficient way of doing things.